# backup sql server database every hour in server host

Tags: backup

I have desktop application with c# and sql server database.
I want to take a backup every hour and upload it on server host and restore it.
I tried sql server agent job but i want to upload to server

Comment: Create a .bat or .sh script file for back up and with your C# code authenticate the with another server and upload and restore it

Comment: can you send the way of it?